# How to remove black line at the bottom of images

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming, wpbakery

***Links to webpage and sceenshot at bottom of post***

I am re-building a webpage with the plugin WP-bakery. The original webpage does not have any problems. When I try to use the same CSS with the new webpage, there are black lines at the bottom of the images. These images are hyperlinks to other pages, but the black lines do not form under the text, but under the image where the text is on. I tested this by adding a new border to the hyperlinks and a new line showed up under the text, so that is not the problem. I think it has to do with the margin and paddings that are not correct, but I do not know where it goes wrong. Here is the CSS file I used on both websites:

```
.entry-content a img, 
.entry-content a, 
.entry-content a img:hover, 
.entry-content a:hover {
    box-shadow:none;
}

.header-sticky-hide, #colophon, #masthead {display:none !important;}

#content {margin:0;padding:0;}

.keuze-txt   {  margin-top: -75%;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff!important;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    text-align: center;
}

.keuze-txt  p {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.keuze-txt a, 
.keuze-txt strong {
    color:#fff !important;
}

.keuze-txt a {
    line-height:100px;
    padding:10px 15px;
    color:#fff;
}

.kraam .keuze-txt a {
    background:#b8ccea 
}

.ack .keuze-txt a {
    background:#ecc8cd  
}

.baker .keuze-txt a {
    background: #ffbe9f  
}

.keuze-txt em {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    font-style: normal;
}

.keuze-img {   
    margin-top: -130%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-left: 33%;
    border: transparent;
}

.keuze-bg {
    max-height: 100vh;
}

.keuze-bg {
    max-height: 100vh;
}

.keuze-bg img{
    opacity:0.3;
}

.keuze-col:hover .keuze-bg img{
 opacity:1;   
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .keuze-img {
        margin-top: -160%;
        margin-left: 25%;
    }

    .keuze-txt {
        margin-top: -90%;
    }

    .keuze-txt p {
        width:90%;
    }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
[vc_row full_width="stretch_row_content_no_spaces" full_height="yes" css=".vc_custom_1600777042471{background-position: 0 0 !important;background-repeat: repeat !important;}"]
[vc_column width="1/3" el_class="keuze-col kraam" css=".vc_custom_1600778593155{padding-top: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;background-color: #b8ccea !important;}"]
[vc_single_image image="1208" img_size="full" alignment="center" onclick="custom_link" link="https://www.kraamenco.nl/" el_class="keuze-bg" css=".vc_custom_1600778060038{padding-top: 0px !important;padding-right: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;padding-left: 0px !important;}"]
[vc_single_image image="1225" img_size="large" alignment="center" onclick="custom_link" link="https://www.kraamenco.nl/" el_class="keuze-img" css=".vc_custom_1600777981827{padding-top: 0px !important;padding-right: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;padding-left: 0px !important;}"]
[vc_column_text el_class="keuze-txt"]



Kraam & Co staat voor professionaliteit, betrouwbaarheid en jarenlange ervaring op het gebied van kraamzorg in Abcoude en omstreken.


Ga naar Kraam & Co »

[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][vc_column width="1/3" el_class="keuze-col ack" css=".vc_custom_1600778027984{padding-top: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;background-color: #ecc8cd !important;}"]
[vc_single_image image="1209" img_size="full" alignment="center" onclick="custom_link" link="https://www.zorgmaat.nl/home/" el_class="keuze-bg"]
[vc_single_image image="1214" img_size="large" alignment="center" onclick="custom_link" link="https://www.zorgmaat.nl/home/" el_class="keuze-img"]
[vc_column_text el_class="keuze-txt"]


Elke baby is uniek, geen bevalling is gelijk. De kraamverzorgenden van Ack Zorgmaat Kraamzorg zijn erin gespecialiseerd om een kraamtijd tot een heerlijk begin te maken van de nieuwe fase in uw leven.

Ga naar Ack Zorgmaat Kraamzorg »

[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][vc_column width="1/3" el_class="keuze-col baker" css=".vc_custom_1600778043514{padding-top: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;background-color: #ffbe9f !important;}"]
[vc_single_image image="1210" img_size="full" alignment="center" onclick="custom_link" link="https://www.debaker.nl/home" el_class="keuze-bg"]
[vc_single_image image="1228" img_size="full" alignment="center" onclick="custom_link" link="https://www.debaker.nl/home" el_class="keuze-img"]
[vc_column_text el_class="keuze-txt"]


Met ruim 30 jaar ervaring in de kraamzorg weten we waar we het over hebben. Van degene die het intakegesprek met je voert tot aan ons management: kraamzorg zit in onze genen.

Ga naar De Baker Kraamzorg »

[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

Where could the problem originate from? I have spend 3 hours looking at it and rebuild the page many times, but I am unable to find the problem. 
**Links**

Webpage that is working properly:
https://www.zorgmaat.nl/

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic6LO.jpg)

#### Fixed

Added this to custom CSS in WP-bakery and the problem seems gone now.

`.colors-custom .entry-content a, .colors-custom .entry-summary a, .colors-custom .comment-content a, .colors-custom .widget a, .colors-custom .site-footer .widget-area a, .colors-custom .posts-navigation a, .colors-custom .widget_authors a strong { -webkit-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none; }`

Comment: add `display:block` to image.

Comment: @RayeesAC Unfortunatly that doesn't solve it.

Comment: You can use Chrome developer tools to help you identify where that specific line is coming from: Press f12 in your keyboard, select the elements tab, and click on the little square on the upper left corner. After that, you just hover your mouse over your line and then click. You will se your html element as well as your css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked your website and the following page.
https://www.zorgmaat.nl/

You have problem with your box shadow. If you want to remove or change the color you just need to simply change this code. Put your color code in the RBG area.

```
box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgb(37 32 32);
```

To completely remove it set it to none.

```
box-shadow: none;
```

Hope this will work for you.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I just saw this problem and fixed it on my other website. However I marked your comment as a solution